# Вывести квадраты натуральных чисел при помощи "+" и "-"

Tags: delphi, pascal, freepascal

Нашёл код на просторах интернета но не могу понять что к чему.

---

Задача:

Вывести квадраты натуральных чисел от 0 до n, используя "+" и "-"

```
 k:=0; k_square:=0;
    writeln(k.square);
    while not (k=n) do begin
    k:= k+1;
    k_square:=k_square+k+k-1;
    writeln(k_square);
    end;
```

Answer (score 4):

Вспоминаем алгебру за пятый класс, а именно квадрат суммы:

```
(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2
```

В нашем случае, когда мы вычисляем следующий член ряда, это трансформируется в выражение:

```
(a+1)^2 = a^2 + 2a + 1
```

или, используя только плюсы и минусы:

```
(a+1)^2 = a^2 + (a+1) + (a+1) - 1
```

Вот к этому и отлично подходит ваш код :)

Comment: Зачем `(a+1) + (a+1) - 1`?) Это ведь `a + a + 1`, только лишние 2 операции)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov  А у вас есть a в данной итерации? У вас есть квадрат предыдущего числа и (a+1). Вы, конечно, можете сохранять a, но в задаче это не предусмотрено, как я понимаю

Comment: @Kir_Antipov написано использовать минус при вычислении, вот и используют

Answer (score 1):

Начинаем с 1:

`k_square = 0 + 1 + 1 - 1` (Получается 1, квадрат 2. 1 Остается в переменной)

`k_square = 1 + 2 + 2 - 1` (Получается 4, увадрат 2. 4 Остается в переменной)

`k_square = 4 + 3 + 3 - 1` (Получается 9, квадрат 3. 9 Остается в переменной)

И так далее.
Так можно сделать с любым числом, формула приблизительно такая:

```
Квадрат числа = (Квадрат предыдущего числа) + (число квадрат которого мы ищем) + (число квадрат которого мы ищем) - 1;
```

Ещё один пример:

42_square = 1681(квадрат 41) + 42 + 42 - 1 = 1764 = 42^2

Comment: а каким образом я должен при решении этой задачи догадаться до данной формулы?

Comment: @ИванШкурко Честно - не знаю. В теории если посидеть над листом бумаги с учебником можно догадаться. Логика.

Comment: Записать ряд квадратов `0 1 4 9 16 25` и разности между ними `1 3 5 7 9 11`

Comment: @ИванШкурко: тут догадываться не надо. Арифметика для пятиклашек. `(n + 1)^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1`, что читается как `квадрат каждого следующего числа равняется сумме квадрата предыдущего числа, его удвоенного произведения и единицы`. Вам же дали формулу: `(n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2(n+1) - 1 = n^2 + 2n + 1`, которой быть как раз не должно, ибо это усложнение изначальной

Comment: @MBo Это то свойство квадратов натуральных чисел, которое я пытаюсь вбить в головы своим детям :) (с переменным успехом).

Comment: @Igor Хорошо, если это пробудит интерес к поиску несложных закономерностей и вообще "как всё устроено"